# Reload table without refreshing whole page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm fetching data in a table from database, and there are three buttons update,delete and active/inactive button,, all three have their own functionalities, but after the event it has to reload the updated data in table. I'm able to reload whole page but i want to reload only the table content,, I have less knowledge about Javascript and ajax.. I'm not getting proper way to proceed with ajax.. Please help me with any procedure that can can solve my problem.. How correctly i can integrate in my code.

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION))
{
  header("Location: ../vendor/login.php");
}
$mpage = "printer";
$page = "list_printer.php";

include '../header.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Printer Lists
   
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Printer</a></li>
        <li class="active">List Printers</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          

    <?php
  
 

  //echo session_id();
  $email1 = $_SESSION['email'];
  $Vendor_id="SELECT Vendor_id FROM vendors where email = '$email1' ";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$Vendor_id);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 
      $sql = "SELECT Vendor_pricing_id, status, printer_name,process,material,color,strength,surface_finish,per_gram_charge,per_hour_charge FROM vendor_pricing where Vendors_Vendor_id= $row[0]";
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (!$query) {
       die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
      }
      
    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $_SESSION['v_id']=$_POST['v_id'];
$update=$_POST['v_id'];
$p_gram=$_POST['p_gram'];
$p_hour=$_POST['p_hour'];


$qry=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `vendor_pricing` SET `per_hour_charge`='$p_hour',`per_gram_charge`='$p_gram' WHERE `Vendor_pricing_id`='$update'");  

//echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Updated!","Successfully!","success");';
  echo '}, 200);</script>';


//echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
  
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
 $update=$_POST['v_id'];
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE vendor_pricing SET status = 'inactive' where Vendor_pricing_id=$update");
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
} 
if(isset($_POST['link'])) {
 $update=$_POST['v_id']; $st=$_POST['link'];

 if($st=="active")
 { mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE vendor_pricing SET status = 'inactive' where Vendor_pricing_id=$update");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";}
 else { mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE vendor_pricing SET status = 'active' where Vendor_pricing_id=$update"); 
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";}
 
}     
   ?>
    
    
          <div class="box table-responsive no-padding">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">List of all Printers</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div id="response" class="box-body">
   
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                                            <th width="10%">Printer Name</th>
                                            <th>Process</th>
           <th>Material</th>
                                            <th>Color</th>
                                            <th>Strength</th>
                                            <th>Surface Finish</th>
           <th padding>per Gram</th>
                                            <th>per Hour</th>
           <th >Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
  
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   $vid=$row['Vendor_pricing_id'];
   $p_name=$row['printer_name'];
   $pro=$row['process'];
   $mat=$row['material'];
   $color=$row['color'];
   $type=$row['strength'];
   $sur=$row['surface_finish'];
   $p_gram=$row['per_gram_charge'];
   $p_hour=$row['per_hour_charge'];
   $st=$row['status']; if ($st=="active"){ $link='inactive';} 
      else { $link='active';}
  
           
       ?>
    <tr>
     <form method="post">
     <td><?php echo $vid;?>
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $vid;?>" name="v_id">
     </td>
     <td><?php echo $p_name;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $pro;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $mat;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $color;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $sur;?></td>
     <td style="padding:9px !important; margin:0px !important;" ><input type="text" style="background:none!important; width:45px; border:none !important; border-color:none;" value="<?php echo $p_gram;?>" name="p_gram"></td>
     <td style="padding:9px !important; margin:0px !important;"><input type="text" style="background:none!important; width:45px; border:none !important; border-color:none;"  value="<?php echo $p_hour;?>" name="p_hour"></td>
     <td>
                    
     <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-small">Update</button>
     <button type="link" name="link" value="<?php echo $st;?>" class="btn btn-default btn-warning btn-small" style="color:white" ><?php echo $link;?></button>
                    <button type="delete" name="delete" value="delete" class="btn btn-default btn-warning btn-small" style="background:#ED5E68; color:white" >Delete</button>
      
                    
      </td>
      
     </tr>
      </form>     
     <?php
  }
  
  ?>
  
  
             
               
                </tbody>
               
              </table>
       </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
 
<?php

include '../footer.php';

?>
</html>
```

using `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";` this line of code I'm able to refresh whole page,, please help how can I reload only table

Comment: thank u sir,, plz help me out with one more doubt,,  Is it possible to refresh my table after those events???? so that i will be sure that im goin in right way

Comment: Just do some research on datatable, which will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: thank u sir,, sure i will work on it

Comment: Follow below links for beginning.  http://www.phpzag.com/load-and-refresh-jquery-datatable-with-php/ and https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ it will easy your work, just try it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reload a specific html element by using a server side script.

You need to research on AJAX which can do exactly what you want.